# setting new properties in category interface/implementation

Tags: objective-c, ios, categories

Ok, so I have this, but it wont work:

```
@interface UILabel (touches)

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isMethodStep;

@end


@implementation UILabel (touches)

-(BOOL)isMethodStep {
    return self.isMethodStep;
}

-(void)setIsMethodStep:(BOOL)boolean {
    self.isMethodStep = boolean;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(self.isMethodStep){
        // set all labels to normal font:
        UIFont *toSet = (self.font == [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16]) ? [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16] : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16];

        id superView = self.superview;
        for(id theView in [(UIView *)superView subviews])
            if([theView isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
                [(UILabel *)theView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:16]];

        self.font = toSet;
    }
}

@end
```

If I take out the getter and setter methods then it doesn't work it tells me I need to create some getter and setter methods (or use @synthesize - but putting @synthesize in the @implementation throws an error too). But with the getter and setter methods I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS and a crash. Any ideas? Thanks

Tom

Comment: This guy 'Dave DeLong' posted an answer that you should check out... it's probably the "correct" way to do what you want... :) [here's the link...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146183/instance-variables-for-objective-c-categories)

Comment: Associative reference is solution...   find nice tutorial here http://www.techpaa.com/2012/04/adding-properties-to-categories-and.html

Comment: Also, your `isMethodStep` getter is an infinitely recursive function. That's why you're getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash. `self.isMethodStep` is equivalent to `[self isMethodStep]`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is not possible to add members and properties to an existing class via a category — only methods.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html

One possible workaround is to write "setter/getter-like" methods, that uses a singleton to save the variables, that would had been the member.

```
-(void)setMember:(MyObject *)someObject
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [MySingleton sharedRegistry];
    [dict setObject:someObject forKey:self];
}

-(MyObject *)member
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [MySingleton sharedRegistry];
    return [dict objectforKey:self];
}
```

or — of course — write a custom class, that inherits from UILabel

---

Note that nowadays an *associated object* can be injected during runtime. [The Objective C Programming Language: Associative References](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html)

Comment: "or — of course — write a custom class, that inherits from UILabel" would be much less faffy. :) bad news eh? ah... well, thank you. :)

Comment: You should use [NSValue valueWithPointer:self] as the key, not self.

Comment: @Dustin: as I pointed out in my edit, there is no need to use this ancient code nowadays anymore — if it ever was wise to fake properties at all. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Avoid associated objects.  Bad form.

Comment: @ZaBlanc, I agree. actually I never used them. But the question is about properties in categories. than they should be mentioned.

Comment: what do `MySingleton` and `MyObject` represent, can you give an example?

Comment: any singleton, any object.

Answer (score 4):

Checked all answers and did not find the most common solution:

```c
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static void const *key;

@interface ClassName (CategoryName)
@property (nonatomic) BOOL myProperty;
@end

@implementation ClassName (CategoryName)
- (BOOL)myProperty {
    return [objc_getAssociatedObject(self, key) boolValue];
}

- (void)setMyProperty:(BOOL)value {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, key, @(value), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}
@end
```

swift:

```swift
private struct AssociatedKeys {
    static var keyName = "keyName"
}

extension Foo {
    var bar: Any! {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.keyName)
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.keyName , newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a way, which may not be ideal, but does work.
For it to work, you will need to create a category for a class X and can only be used on **subclasses** of the same X (e.g. category `UIView (Background)` can be used with class `MyView : UIView`, but not directly with `UIView`)

```
// UIView+Background.h

@interface UIView (Background)

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *hexColor;

- (void)someMethodThatUsesHexColor;

@end

// UIView+Background.h

@implementation UIView (Background)

@dynamic hexColor; // Must be declared as dynamic

- (void)someMethodThatUsesHexColor {
    NSLog(@"Color %@", self.hexColor);
}

@end
```

Then

```
// MyView.m

#import "UIView+Background.h"

@interface MyView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *hexColor;

@end

@implementation MyView ()

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setHexColor:@"#BABACA"];
    [self someMethodThatUsesHexColor];
}

@end
```

Using this method, you will need to "redeclare" your properties, but after that, you can do all of its manipulation inside your category.

Answer (score 1):

You could inject an associated object during runtime.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@interface UIView (Private)

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint initialTouchPoint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *alertWindow;

@end

@implementation UIView (Private)

@dynamic initialTouchPoint, alertWindow;

- (CGPoint)initialTouchPoint {
    return CGPointFromString(objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(initialTouchPoint)));
}

- (void)setInitialTouchPoint:(CGPoint)initialTouchPoint {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(initialTouchPoint), NSStringFromCGPoint(initialTouchPoint), OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

- (void)setAlertWindow:(UIWindow *)alertWindow {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(alertWindow), alertWindow, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (UIWindow *)alertWindow {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(alertWindow));
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Warning: This property would have a unique value for all the instances of the class.

This worked for me, but only because I had only one instance of this class in my app.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AVAudioPlayer (AstroAVAudioPlayer)

@property (nonatomic) BOOL redPilot;

@end


#import "AVAudioPlayer+AstroAVAudioPlayer.h"

@implementation AVAudioPlayer (AstroAVAudioPlayer)

BOOL _redPilot;

-(void) setRedPilot:(BOOL)redPilot
{
    _redPilot = redPilot;
}

-(BOOL) redPilot
{
    return _redPilot;
}

@end
```

Comment: This answer should be flagged as incorrect. The implementation above only allocates one property called _redPilot for all instances of AVAudioPlayer. In other words, if you have three instances of AVAudioPlayer, then avAudioPlayer1.redPilot == avAudioPlayer2.redPilot == avAudioPlayer3.redPilot always.

Comment: @nobular, You're right, Sir. Indeed in my case I had only one instance of AVAudioPlayer, so I wasn't caring much about that. I answered this here anyway, because I thought this might be helpful for someone, for example someone like me. I would edit the answer so it warns about the above-mentioned issue.

Comment: Here's a technique that I've used in the past for solving the lack of properties on categories: http://www.techpaa.com/2012/04/adding-properties-to-categories-and.html

Comment: In my case, this is a perfect solution. I'm trying to add a NSDateFormatter to the category of NSDate (maybe I'm crazy) to have only one instance of the formatter in all of my NSDate objects. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Floydian, you know, there is a saying: "It's not a bug. It's a feature." :) So if you want such a feature, go for it, if it does the right job for you.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I found to this was to just give each object that you want flagged a unique tag.

I made a UILabel category to add custom fonts to all my labels but on some i wanted them to be bold so i did this ->

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    [self addCustomFont];   
}

- (void) addCustomFont {
    if (self.tag == 22) {
        [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:SEGOE_BOLD size:self.font.pointSize]];
    }else{
        [self setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:SEGOE_LIGHT size:self.font.pointSize]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if since **Xcode 7** (7.0.1, 7A1001), properties are supported in categories. I noticed that **Xcode** generates categories now for *Core Data* subclasses.

For example, I got the files:

**Location+CoreDataProperties.h**

```
#import "Location.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface Location (CoreDataProperties)

@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *altitude;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *longitude;

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

**Location+CoreDataProperties.m**

```
#import "Location+CoreDataProperties.h"

@implementation Location (CoreDataProperties)

@dynamic altitude;
@dynamic latitude;
@dynamic longitude;

@end
```

So looks like properties in categories might work now. I haven't tested on non-*Core Data* classes.

What I've noticed is that they do include the category file back into the original class:

**Location.h**

```
@interface Location : NSManagedObject

@end

#import "Location+CoreDataProperties.h"
```

This allows the original class to edit the properties specified by the category.