# private string field in iOS image UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

This is a trick I use a lot in android:

- I take an image with Image Picker: camera or gallery
- I put the image in an ImageView
- I also put the image url in the ImageView, in the tag field
- so later when I need the url of an image (to send to server), I grab it from the imageView's tag.

But tag in iOS is a bit different from android: in iOS it's just a number. So is there such a way of piggybacking on an UIButton on iOS: basically any field whatsoever that is available for storing a text and which the user cannot see?

Comment: UIButton. **Not** UIImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an analogous field on a UIImageView.  Your best bet may be to subclass UIImageView to add such a property.  In the .h file for the new class, do something like:

```
@interface SubclassedUIImageView : UIImageView

@property (strong, nonatomic, copy) NSString *url;

@end
```

Then assign the url value to SubclassedUIImageView in imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:.  Assuming you're using Interface Builder, to use the subclassed UIImageView, you drop a UIImageView control onto the parent view, go to the Identity inspector, and change the Custom Class field to the name of your subclassed UIImageView.

Comment: I find this a wee bit of an overkill. But it's probably the quickest option if indeed there is no native way.

Answer (score 1):

Natively, there's no way to do this. However, you can use a category and store the text in an associated object:

```
@interface UIImageView (StringTagAdditions)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *stringTag;
@end

@implementation UIImageView (StringTagAdditions)
static NSString *kStringTagKey = @"StringTagKey";

- (NSString *)stringTag {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, kStringTagKey);
}

- (void)setStringTag:(NSString *)stringTag {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, kStringTagKey, stringTag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}
@end
```

More info @ http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/

Comment: A computer science professor said that it's not good to add category to classes I (i.e. my team) didn't create

Comment: You should find out exactly why your professor thinks "it's not good".

Answer (score 1):

This type of thing has been asked before, but you could pull this off with a `UIButton` category that adds getter/setter like methods that store this value for you:

- [setting new properties in category interface/implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098753/setting-new-properties-in-category-interface-implementation)
- [Objective-C: Property / instance variable in category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733104/objective-c-property-instance-variable-in-category)
- http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/adding-properties-category-using-associated-objects.html

Or you could subclass `UIButton` and add the property you need. There are lots of options, but I'm unclear on what you mean by "the user cannot see"?

Comment: I remember a computer science professor saying that it's not good to add category to classes I (i.e. my team) didn't create)

Comment: No sweat, not sure I agree with your professor though. I also mentioned that you could subclass `UIButton`, :-)